# Querying EMF model using xpath e4.emf.xpath.XPathContext

Tags: java, xml, xpath, e4, emf

I have an emf model from which I have get selected EObjects based on some conditions.

For this I tried using org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath.XPathContext. But the XPATH expression is not giving any result.

Following is the sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
   <codeAnalysis xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://myTool/codeAnalysis/CommonReport">
<Header>
<Title>My_Report</Title>
<Date>02/05/2016</Date>
<CreatedBy>xyz</CreatedBy>
<Software>
  <checkpoint>0</checkpoint>
  <StartComponent>ABC</StartComponent>
  <StartFolder>E:\TestProject</StartFolder>
</Software>
<Environment>
  <Version>8.1.2</Version>
  <ToolVersion>1.33.0.qualifier</ToolVersion>      
</Environment>
</Header>
<Report>
<Component name="MSI">
    <File name="TestProject/comp/a.h">
        <Function name="TIME_STAMP_GET_TIMER_VALUE">
            <Complain lfd="1">
                <MetricName>STM29</MetricName>
                <Value>0</Value>
             </Complain>
        </Function>
    </File>
</Component>
</Report>
</codeAnalysis>
```

I want to get the value of codeAnalysis/Header/Software/StartComponent

Following is the code which I have written

```
    public void emfQueryTest() {
    try {
        String filePath = "E:\\03Projects\\Test.xml";
        ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
        resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("xml", new MetricCommonReportResourceFactoryImpl());
        resourceSet.getPackageRegistry().put(MetricCommonReportPackage.eNS_URI, MetricCommonReportPackage.eINSTANCE);
        Resource resource = (Resource)resourceSet.getResource(URI.createFileURI(filePath), true);
        if (resource != null) {
            resource.load(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
            if (resource.getContents() != null && resource.getContents().size() > 0) {
                CodeAnalysis metricCodeAnalysis = (MetricCommonReport.CodeAnalysis) resource.getContents().get(0);
                System.out.println(metricCodeAnalysis.getHeader().getTitle());
                XPathContextFactory<EObject> f = EcoreXPathContextFactory.newInstance();
                XPathContext xPathContext = f.newContext(metricCodeAnalysis);
                Iterator<MetricCommonReport.Software> it = xPathContext.iterate("/codeAnalysis/Header/Software");                   

                while( it.hasNext() ) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                    System.out.println("    " + it.next().getStartComponent());
                }  
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This xml is loaded correctly. But it is not printing any value for startComponent. In fact Iterator it doesn't have any element? Where I went wrong? Please somebody correct me.

The same XPath expression in Java is giving correct node and value.

Comment: Your code seems to be using `/QACCodeAnalysis` rather than `/codeAnalysis` as the root element.

Comment: even if I use /codeAnalysis the same result.